# gridjs Make whole row a link instead of link in columns

Tags: gridjs

I am using gridjs.io and I have the last column with a link in it.

There are a lot of columns and instead of cramping it further with that column as a link I would like to have it so the whole row can be clicked as a link.

I have searched and tested and I can not find anything that works.

Any suggestions?